# How to get segmemnted control like twitter?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

[image]

I've been trying to find out how to do this using react native , I looked at a package that has segmented control for IOS and android. But how can i accomplish this , because on IOS it doesn't seem to look just like this. And i don't know how i could possibly style it to look like that

Comment: Have you tried searching? Here's the first thing I found (30-seconds worth of search) that has an example that looks much like what you're asking: https://medium.com/swlh/create-elegant-segmented-controls-for-ios-using-swift-25fa4e642ac1

Comment: Dang wow I never thought of that, wait actually yea I did try searching maybe you worded your search differently than I did that’s probably why you found it in 30 seconds, and I’m on here trying to find a answer

Comment: I didn't mean for it to sound bad -- I was simply asking. I searched for `swift underline segmented control`. Might be worth noting: that is not necessarily a `UISegmentedControl`... here is an example of similar UI that uses buttons in a stack view, allowing for horizontal scrolling if the list of buttons is too wide to fit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61327604/6257435

Comment: My bad , sorry thanks this really helped tho